# How to join/merge multiple(18 to 20) files with the same interval(secs) in python

Tags: python

I have 16 to 20 files(tab-delimited/comma-delimited) each file contains 2 columns. The columns are as below.
1. Interval (msec) 
2. IOPS

I want to join all the 20 files 
for ex:

file 1:

```
1000, 11217              
2000, 12789              
3001, 12022              
4000, 14028
```

file 2:

```
1000, 11236
2000, 12789
3001, 12022
4000, 14028
```

In this way, I have 20 input files. these files will be generated based on the threads.

The output should be like

```
1000, 11217, 11236
2000, 12789, 12803
3000, 12156
3001, 12022
4000, 14028, 13889
```

Can anyone please suggest which will be the best way to merge the files.

Thank u in advance

Comment: How large are the files? If they are reasonably small, simply read them all in, map into / combine with a dictionary and write out. If they are large such that they do not trivially fit in memory (and are guaranteed in order), iterate each as a stream of lines width-first (that is, advance each file until at the next small line number) and write out after a localized merge: this is effectively the 'merge' step of an N-way merge sort.

Comment: Also, the data in the question should be fixed. I corrected the formatting; not the inaccuracies with the shown input and output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test the script below I have generated some testing data, namely 16 files , each one with 12 records, with a random occurrence of `t` values that are not exactly equal to a multiple of `1000`, using the following helper script

```
from random import random, seed
seed(1234)

for n in range(1, 17):
    with open('f%02d'%n, 'w') as f:
        for t in range(1000,12001,1000):
            print(t+(1 if random()<0.1 else 0),int(random()*10000), sep=', ', file=f)
```

E.g., the file `f07` contains

```
1000, 3812
2000, 9600
3000, 9210
4000, 6852
5000, 8387
6001, 2603
7000, 8578
8000, 1137
9000, 2138
10000, 5875
11001, 8774
12000, 7768
```

The following script uses [`heapq.merge`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge) to order the data that arrives from the sorted files, data filtered by a simple generator that splits the individual record  and adds info wrt the file to which the record belongs, so that we can write uniform records, possibly with void entries.

Use `debug = False` to use the script on your data.

```
'''Usage: python3 merge.py filename1, filename2, ..., filenameout'''
from heapq import merge
from sys import argv, stdout

def reader(fobj, n):
    for line in fobj:
        yield [x.strip() for x in line.split(',')]+[n]

# change to debug = False to run on your data
debug = True
argv = ['']+['f%02d'%n for n in range(1, 17)]+[''] if debug else argv
out  = stdout if debug else open(argv[-1], 'w')

readers = [reader(open(f), n) for n, f in enumerate(argv[1:-1])]
N = len(readers)

# header is "Interval,IOPS01,IOPS02,...,IOPSnn" modify as you like
print('Interval',*('IOPS%02d'%(n+1) for n in range(N)), sep=',', file=out)

# initialize for the loop
t0 = ""
# the loop
for t, iops, n in merge(*readers, key=lambda x:int(x[0])):
    if t != t0:
        if t0: print(t0, *iops_l, sep=',', file=out)
        t0 = t
        iops_l = ['····' if debug else '']*N
    iops_l[n] = '%4s'%iops if debug else iops

# the last record to output
print(t0, *iops_l, sep=',', file=out)
```

Running the program on `f01`, ..., `f16` produces

```
Interval,IOPS01,IOPS02,IOPS03,IOPS04,IOPS05,IOPS06,IOPS07,IOPS08,IOPS09,IOPS10,IOPS11,IOPS12,IOPS13,IOPS14,IOPS15,IOPS16
1000,4407, 889,9569,2956, 477,5845,3812,3079,····,2571,4994,8863,6394,5339,8280,9311
1001,····,····,····,····,····,····,····,····,1400,····,····,····,····,····,····,····
2000,····,2695,3053,1856, 379,8128,9600,····,5880, 283,9501, 709,1964,5371,7242,3195
2001,9109,····,····,····,····,····,····,3949,····,····,····,····,····,····,····,····
3000,5822,6446,····,1194, 876,4995,9210,6827,7535,····,5323,8030,6204,3628,3730,5248
3001,····,····,2767,····,····,····,····,····,····,9906,····,····,····,····,····,····
4000, 839,3552,1773,8294,6993,5490,6852,4005,2986,6665,1455,9396,5018,7121,6750,9895
5000,2368,9335,9547,8177,9450,1309,8387,2812,3305,5156,2432,3797,9101,4568,8340,····
5001,····,····,····,····,····,····,····,····,····,····,····,····,····,····,····,1974
6000,····,5301,8338,6410,····,9253,····,6004,2937,5152,5064, 524, 495,8768,7844,3358
6001,7887,····,····,····,2574,····,2603,····,····,····,····,····,····,····,····,····
7000,6232,····,····,7026,····, 697,8578,5188,8142,····,7734, 801,4680,5435,5463,6949
7001,····,5081,3861,····,4263,····,····,····,····,7595,····,····,····,····,····,····
8000,1485,····,3417,1571,3966,  17,1137,4574,5340,6980,3265,9292,3717,1917,7696, 293
8001,····,1437,····,····,····,····,····,····,····,····,····,····,····,····,····,····
9000,1144,3773,4759,2693,8873,6382,2138,6598,3396,2195,5617,6769,7784,8677,6985,3160
10000,····,····,4708,8404,8185,1482,5875,7255,3210,6531,5991,6930,  87,9459,9566,····
10001,4867,5875,····,····,····,····,····,····,····,····,····,····,····,····,····, 556
11000, 645,5573,8815,7935,8586,4327,····,1037,7596,6827,3717,8642,9853,8470,3549,4239
11001,····,····,····,····,····,····,8774,····,····,····,····,····,····,····,····,····
12000,4658,9373,7810, 707,7024,2071,7768,7940,5482,5641,7628,3714,5999,7547,1883,9796
```

After I have substituted `debug = True` with `debug = False`, the program can be run like this

```
$ python3 merge.py f01 f02 f03 f04 f05 f06 f07 f08 f09 f10 f11 f12 f13 f14 f15 f16 OUT
$ cat OUT
Interval,IOPS01,IOPS02,IOPS03,IOPS04,IOPS05,IOPS06,IOPS07,IOPS08,IOPS09,IOPS10,IOPS11,IOPS12,IOPS13,IOPS14,IOPS15,IOPS16
1000,4407, 889,9569,2956, 477,5845,3812,3079,,2571,4994,8863,6394,5339,8280,9311
1001,,,,,,,,,1400,,,,,,,
2000,,2695,3053,1856, 379,8128,9600,,5880, 283,9501, 709,1964,5371,7242,3195
2001,9109,,,,,,,3949,,,,,,,,
3000,5822,6446,,1194, 876,4995,9210,6827,7535,,5323,8030,6204,3628,3730,5248
3001,,,2767,,,,,,,9906,,,,,,
4000, 839,3552,1773,8294,6993,5490,6852,4005,2986,6665,1455,9396,5018,7121,6750,9895
5000,2368,9335,9547,8177,9450,1309,8387,2812,3305,5156,2432,3797,9101,4568,8340,
5001,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1974
6000,,5301,8338,6410,,9253,,6004,2937,5152,5064, 524, 495,8768,7844,3358
6001,7887,,,,2574,,2603,,,,,,,,,
7000,6232,,,7026,, 697,8578,5188,8142,,7734, 801,4680,5435,5463,6949
7001,,5081,3861,,4263,,,,,7595,,,,,,
8000,1485,,3417,1571,3966,  17,1137,4574,5340,6980,3265,9292,3717,1917,7696, 293
8001,,1437,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
9000,1144,3773,4759,2693,8873,6382,2138,6598,3396,2195,5617,6769,7784,8677,6985,3160
10000,,,4708,8404,8185,1482,5875,7255,3210,6531,5991,6930,  87,9459,9566,
10001,4867,5875,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 556
11000, 645,5573,8815,7935,8586,4327,,1037,7596,6827,3717,8642,9853,8470,3549,4239
11001,,,,,,,8774,,,,,,,,,
12000,4658,9373,7810, 707,7024,2071,7768,7940,5482,5641,7628,3714,5999,7547,1883,9796
$
```

Comment: I tried the above program while running i got error as iops_l is not defined so i tried defining it after t0="" as iops_l[]. The op file got created with only one word Interval. The values for interval was not populated and also othr headers iops_1,iops_2 was not populated. Could you please help

Comment: Sindhu, I'm sorry but at the moment I cannot help you any more than this. ፨ I have shown you how to get reproducible test data and on that reproducible test data my script runs w/o any problem… I really fail to understand your issue (I mean, the reasons behind it) from the scarce info you provided in your comment. ፨ re `iops_l` being undefined, in my script it is defined (in the `if t != t0` body) before it is used, so I really do not understand what's up. ፨ Could you possibly edit your question to show the details of what's going wrong?

Comment: BTW, if you edit your question please remember to ping me by adding a comment under this answer, otherwise I could miss your edit

Comment: hi gboffi, If I am running the script above I am getting the below error message.  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/sindhus/Desktop/Fio/merge.py", line 33, in <module>
    print(t0, *iops_l, sep=',', file=outh)
NameError: name 'iops_l' is not defined

Comment: What you see could possibly happen if you never ever enter the loop, and this is possible only if the program has opened no file... did you invoked the program using a list of input files + the output file on the command line? I suspect that you just wrote `python merge.py`, and now I understand better your previous comment... ፨ I have edited my answer to give an example of an invocation of the program with `debug = False` in the source.

Comment: Hi Gboffi, I am invoking merge.py script as:   !python C:/Users/Desktop/merge.py C:/Users/Desktop/f1.txt C:/Users/Desktop/f2.txt C:/Users/Desktop/f3.txt C:/Users/Desktop/Fout.csv.  I am using anaconda so I am using ! python. Is anything wrong in this invocation. Its as you have specified in the example above

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer... it's rather a sort of *very loong, formatted comment*.

---

When you have this kind of problems, that is the other side says everything is fine with their script and you see that it's not working, you could guess that there are *environmental* issues in the middle, their environment being different from yours...

What can YOU do to solve the problem? taking the current state of your problem as an example

1. see what happens when you recreate their environment:

   - in a new folder (please, not everything on your desktop) copy the helper script `from random import random, seed ...etc etc` and copy `merge.py`
   - run the helper script
   - check that the example files are correctly generated
   - run `merge.py` with `debug=True`

   if what you get is what was shown to you, then for sure it's your environment
2. in a new folder, please a new folder,

   - copy your data files and `merge.py`, edit `merge.py` and set `debug=False`
   - run the script `!python file1 file2 file3 output` (with correct file names)
   - if it works, it was something in your desktop that was interfering (what? for now, don't care, it works in a fresh environment and that's all)
   - if it doesn't work, you have to see for yourself

     - edit `merge.py` and place `print`s to check what the script is really doing wrt what the script is supposed to do and what it's really doing, because you *experienced* a mismatch and you want to understand the cause of it...
     - e.g., the `argv` list, does it contains the items that are expected? it's easy to add `for arg in argv: print(arg)` to the code and see if what you get is the program name (`argv[0]`) the input file names and last the output file name

To help you I'll show you a debugging version of the script, where the script is going to output **a lot** of details about what it is *really* doing, but please try hard to understand what is printed, why it was printed and what are the implications when you spot a problem...

Here we are

```
$ cat mergedbg.py
'''Usage: python3 merge.py filename1, filename2, ..., filenameout'''

from heapq import merge
from sys import argv, stdout

def reader(fobj, n):
    for line in fobj:
        yield [x.strip() for x in line.split(',')]+[n]

print('Contents of argv',
      *((n, arg) for n, arg in enumerate(argv)), sep='\n\t')

# open the files for reading
readers = []
for n, fname in enumerate(argv[1:-1]):
    try:
        print('Trying to open', fname, end='... ')
        readers.append(reader(open(fname), n))
        print('OK')
    except:
        print('oops, something went wrong!')

# open the file for writing
try:
    print('Trying to open', argv[-1], 'for writing', end='... ')
    out  = open(argv[-1], 'w')
    print('OK')
except:
    print('oops, something went wrong!')

N = len(readers)
print("About to loop over %d files"%N)

# header is "Interval,IOPS01,IOPS02,...,IOPSnn" modify as you like
print('Interval',*('IOPS%02d'%(n+1) for n in range(N)), sep=',', file=out)

# initialize 
t0, icount, ocount = "", 0, 0
for t, iops, n in merge(*readers, key=lambda t:int(t[0])):
    icount += 1
    print((icount, n, t, iops), end = '')
    if t != t0:
        if t0:
            ocount += 1
            print(t0, *iops_l, sep=',', file=out)
        t0 = t
        iops_l = ['']*N 
    iops_l[n] = iops

# the last record to output
ocount += 1
print(t0, *iops_l, sep=',', file=out)
# summary
print("\n%4d input records read,"%icount,
      "\n%4d output records written (1 header, %d data)."%(ocount+1, ocount))
```

Of course you have to run the script with your filenames...

```
$ python3 mergedbg.py f01 f02 f03 f04 OUTdbg
Contents of argv
        (0, 'mergedbg.py')
        (1, 'f01')
        (2, 'f02')
        (3, 'f03')
        (4, 'f04')
        (5, 'OUTdbg')
Trying to open f01... OK
Trying to open f02... OK
Trying to open f03... OK
Trying to open f04... OK
Trying to open OUTdbg for writing... OK
About to loop over 4 files
(1, 0, '1000', '4407')(2, 1, '1000', '889')(3, 2, '1000', '9569')(4, 3, '1000', '2956')(5, 1, '2000', '2695')(6, 2, '2000', '3053')(7, 3, '2000', '1856')(8, 0, '2001', '9109')(9, 0, '3000', '5822')(10, 1, '3000', '6446')(11, 3, '3000', '1194')(12, 2, '3001', '2767')(13, 0, '4000', '839')(14, 1, '4000', '3552')(15, 2, '4000', '1773')(16, 3, '4000', '8294')(17, 0, '5000', '2368')(18, 1, '5000', '9335')(19, 2, '5000', '9547')(20, 3, '5000', '8177')(21, 1, '6000', '5301')(22, 2, '6000', '8338')(23, 3, '6000', '6410')(24, 0, '6001', '7887')(25, 0, '7000', '6232')(26, 3, '7000', '7026')(27, 1, '7001', '5081')(28, 2, '7001', '3861')(29, 0, '8000', '1485')(30, 2, '8000', '3417')(31, 3, '8000', '1571')(32, 1, '8001', '1437')(33, 0, '9000', '1144')(34, 1, '9000', '3773')(35, 2, '9000', '4759')(36, 3, '9000', '2693')(37, 2, '10000', '4708')(38, 3, '10000', '8404')(39, 0, '10001', '4867')(40, 1, '10001', '5875')(41, 0, '11000', '645')(42, 1, '11000', '5573')(43, 2, '11000', '8815')(44, 3, '11000', '7935')(45, 0, '12000', '4658')(46, 1, '12000', '9373')(47, 2, '12000', '7810')(48, 3, '12000', '707')
  48 input records read, 
  19 output records written (1 header, 18 data).
$ cat OUTdbg 
Interval,IOPS01,IOPS02,IOPS03,IOPS04
1000,4407,889,9569,2956
2000,,2695,3053,1856
2001,9109,,,
3000,5822,6446,,1194
3001,,,2767,
4000,839,3552,1773,8294
5000,2368,9335,9547,8177
6000,,5301,8338,6410
6001,7887,,,
7000,6232,,,7026
7001,,5081,3861,
8000,1485,,3417,1571
8001,,1437,,
9000,1144,3773,4759,2693
10000,,,4708,8404
10001,4867,5875,,
11000,645,5573,8815,7935
12000,4658,9373,7810,707
$
```

A closing remark, I guess that there is a trivial misunderstanding between us and it seems that I have a difficult time in finding the problem... may I honestly suggest that you seek the help of some colleague of yours, with even a limited knowledge of Python, because that can be terribly helpful, they looking at your process over your shoulder and ask you questions as you move on yes, that could be terribly helpful.

That said, please ask me other questions as you want :-)

Comment: Hi Gboffi, Yes I guess... I had env issues... Tried this in linux it worked... Thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome, thank you for the appreciation. Have a nice day!